# Kubernetes cluster on GCE from Instances/Group

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, gcloud

Have Kubernetes computation cluster running on GCE, reasonable happy so far. I know if I created K-cluster, I'll get to see nodes as VM Instances and cluster as Instance group. I would like to do other way around - create instances/group and make K-cluster out of it so it could be managed by Kubernetes. Reason I want to do so is to try and make nodes preemptible, which might better fit my workload.

So question - Kubernetes cluster with preemptible nodes how-to. I could do either one or another now, but not together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a patch out for review at the moment (#[12384](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/pull/12384)) that makes a configuration option to mark the nodes in the instance group as preemptible. If you are willing to build from head, this should be available as a configuration option in the next couple of days. In the meantime, you can see from the patch how easy it is to modify the GCE startup scripts to make your VMs preemptible.